# Is there a way to know if a future will throw on get()?

Tags: c++, exception, future

Is there a way to know if a future will throw on `get()`?

Say I have some some like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <future>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  srand(time(0));
  auto randomSuccess = [] {
             if (rand() >= rand())
                  throw std::runtime_error("Random exception");
             };
  auto f = std::async(std::launch::deferred, randomSuccess);

  f.wait();
  // from here, the future is valid
  std::cout << "Now future is " << (f.valid() ? "valid" : "not valid yet") << std::endl;

  f.get(); // how to know if this will throw?
}
```

I would just like to 'spy' internal state of the future, just like `bool valid() const noexcept;` does by keeping the future untouched (function would be const), that's why putting a `try/catch` block is not what I want to do.

Comment: Use `try`/`catch`?

Comment: What is your intention to know "up-front" how a function call will throw an exception?

Comment: There is only one way to find out.

Comment: added so more explanation to make the question clearer.

Comment: And are you asking for a generic solution or for the specific code above?

Comment: the code is just a dummy illustration code, I would like a generic solution if it exists...

Comment: If you're not specifically interested in that hunk of code, don't ask "Is there a way to know if a future will throw on get() in the following hunk of code?"

Comment: You can't determine whether an arbitrary piece of code will throw an exception. If you could, you could solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which you can't.

Comment: @OznOg: "*I would just like to 'spy' internal state of the future, just like `bool valid() const noexcept;`*" That's not what that function does. It merely tells you if the `future` is broken (that is, it's connected to a promise that will deliver a value), not whether the future value has been delivered. `f` was valid before the wait call.

Comment: @molbdnilo: yes, I added the wait call that was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You might do some gymnastic to have the result:

```
template <typename T>
bool will_throw(std::future<T>& fut)
{
    std::promise<T> promise;
    try {
        if constexpr (std::is_void<T>::value) {
            fut.get();
            promise.set_value();
        } else {
            promise.set_value(fut.get());
        }
        fut = promise.get_future(); // Restore future value
        return false;
    } catch (...) {
        promise.set_exception(std::current_exception());
        fut = promise.get_future(); // Restore future exception
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e497e615c1cfb9f)

Comment: Does not respect the condition for constness, but this is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

based on the same idea than @Jarod42 without need for c++17 support

```
template <class T>
bool will_throw(std::future<T> &f) {
    bool throws = false;
    auto new_f = std::async(std::launch::deferred, [&throws, &f] () {
       try {
           return f.get();
       } catch (...) {
           throws = true;
           throw;
       }
    });

    new_f.wait();

    f = std::move(new_f);

    return throws;
}
```